# NotificationCenter observer with generic class

Tags: ios, swift, macos, generics

I have a generic class:

```
open class GenericClass<T:MyClass>: NSObject {

     public init(_ myParam:Int) {            
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.someFunc), name: .MyName, object: nil)
     }

     func someFunc() {

     }
}
```

But i wonder that those code doesn't work. I get error:

> 'self' used before super.init call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to call the initialiser of `NSObject` (The class you're subclassing):

```
open class GenericClass<T:MyClass>: NSObject {

    public init(_ myParam:Int) {
        super.init()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.someFunc), name: .MyName, object: nil)
    }

    func someFunc() {

    }
}
```